# How do I get parameters from form redirect?

Tags: forms, 8, redirection

I've made a form and I'm trying to get the submit result into a redirect page with URL api:

```
 public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state)
    {

    $metier=$form_state->getValue('metier');
    $position=$form_state->getValue('position');

    //$form_state->setRedirect('recherche.resultat',array('param'=>'test');

    $url = new Url('recherche.resultat');
    $url->setOptions(array('param'=>'test2'));
    $url->setRouteParameters(array('param'=>'test2'));

    $form_state->setRedirectUrl($url);

    drupal_set_message("envoyer");

}
```

I set two options :

```
$url->setOptions(array('param'=>'test2'));
```

and

```
$url->setRouteParameters(array('param'=>'test2'));
```

The form redirect me and this is my controller :

```
public function resultat()
{
    $request = \Drupal::request();
    $url = Url::createFromRequest($request);
    kint($url);
    kint($url->getOptions());
    kint($url->getRouteParameters());
    return array('#markup'=>t('test'));

}
```

The two methods :

```
    kint($url->getOptions());
    kint($url->getRouteParameters());
```

are empty

This is my routing :

```
 recherche.resultat:
  path: '/resultat'
  defaults:
    _title: 'resultat'
    _controller: '\Drupal\recherche\Controller\ResultatRechercheController::resultat'
  requirements:
     _permission: 'access content'
```

The parameters are in the URL and I can get them with $_GET but how can I get with the URL API?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok i got it by this way :

So i have 2 parameters from my form to pass to my controller :

```
public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state)
{

    $metier=$form_state->getValue('metier');
    $position=$form_state->getValue('position');

    $url = \Drupal\Core\Url::fromRoute('recherche.resultat')
          ->setRouteParameters(array('metier'=>$metier,'position'=>$position));

    $form_state->setRedirectUrl($url);


}
```

The key is in the YAML routing, you need to build your path like that for get parameters ( name of parameters need to be same as your route, see previous function (submitForm)) :

```
recherche.resultat:
  path: '/resultat/{metier}/{position}'
  defaults:
    _title: 'resultat'
    _controller: '\Drupal\recherche\Controller\ResultatRechercheController::resultat'
    metier: ''
    position: ''
  requirements:
     _permission: 'access content'
```

And in my controller for get my parameters :

Class: ResultatRechercheController

```
 public function resultat($metier, $position)
    {

        kint($metier);
        kint($position);

        return array('#markup'=>t('la premiere spécialite est @specialite',array('@specialite'=>'test')));

    }
```

And the URL is clean :

> localhost:8888//monsite.com/resultat/{metier}/{position}

Answer (score 3):

You can get the get attributes directly from the request object `\Drupal::request()->attributes->get('param');` or `\Drupal::request()->query`

Source: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal.php/function/Drupal%3A%3Arequest/8

Comment: Thank, so how work $url->getOptions or $url->getRouteParameters() ?

Comment: This link says that the usage is discouraged.

Answer (score 0):

In a block form, you can simply add your parameters in your form redirect url, without routing :

```
public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  # get form data
    $form_var = $form_state->getValue('input_name')
    ...

  # set form data in url redirect
  $option = [
    'query' => ['testvar' => $form_var],
  ];
  $url = Url::fromUri('internal:/my_url/redirect', $option);

  $form_state->setRedirectUrl($url);
}
```

Then retrieve it and clean it :

```
# retrieve query param
$my_var = \Drupal::request()->query->get('testvar');

# clean for a textfield
$my_var_escaped = Html::escape($my_var);
```

Comment: Interesting, i ll try that