# Redirect to a form with an array of Terms as a parameter of buildForm

Tags: 8, views

Here is my use case:

1-I select few nodes from a view with VBO

2-I run a custom action on those nodes

3-As a result, this action create an array of Terms ($resultedTerms)

My goal, after that, is to redirect the user to a custom form.

This custom form will use $resultedTerms to create a lot of widgets.

How can I achieve this? How can I pass $resultedTerms to the buildForm function of my custom form?

Note that I do not want to save the original selected nodes in the vbo view...

Comment: Do you read this? https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/167757/how-do-i-get-parameters-from-form-redirect

Comment: @Alen Simonyan: many thanks for this link. This is solving the first part of my question (as the answer from Taggart Jensen). What needs to be solved is the fact that I don't have a `$form_state` available. This is because I am not in a submit form handler, I am in the `executeMultiple` function of the `ActionBase` class.

Comment: Yes. In that case you need to read this --- https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/form-api/introduction-to-form-api : scroll down to the bottom of the page, see the example, I think it is just that you want -> http://joxi.ru/8Anj98yijBVwZA.

The Alternative way can be passing parameters with url but I don't think it is a good choice --- https://www.valuebound.com/resources/blog/how-to-pass-page-callback-arguments-in-Drupal-8

Comment: Thank you @Alen Simonyan. Now I can create a form with the needed arguments (using request or form_builder). But I still miss a way to redirect to this form from `function executeMultiple`. In other words, I have my arguments (`$resultedTerms`) available in the `function executeMultiple` of the class `ActionBase` and I need to redirect to my custom form (with `$resultedTerms` as argument) after the completion of this VBO action.

Comment: There are many ways to redirect from Drupal 8 controller to route. 
Please try these ---
https://gist.github.com/annikaC/722f0a38e734c087d6f0779a1aef6f3b
https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/146185/how-to-create-a-redirection-in-drupal-8
https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/231391/how-to-redirect-to-frontpage-from-a-controller . 
You need to orientate based on your case.

Answer (score 0):

Yep so your going to have to hook into the VOB results or submit function
I assume you have  already done this.
then in your function you can create a Response such as the following:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernelInterface;

$resultedTerms = [
  'terms' => [1, 2, 7]
];
// Get the current request to re-use some stuff. 
$request = \Drupal::request();
$redirect_request = Request::create(
  '/the-url-to-your-form',
  'POST', // this also can be GET
  $resultedTerms, 
  $request->cookies->all(),
  [],
  $request->server->all()
);
if (is_object($request)) {
  $response = \Drupal::service('http_kernel')->handle($redirect_request, HttpKernelInterface::SUB_REQUEST);
  return $response;
}
```

then in your buildForm function:

```
//Get the post data.
$posted = \Drupal::request()->request->all();
// if using GET try dump($_GET);
if (!empty($posted['terms'])) {
  $form['filed_name']['#default_value'] = $posted['terms'];
}
```

References:
see "static Request create"  at https://api.symfony.com/3.4/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Request.html#method___construct

also see use of this in Drupal core:
core/modules/comment/src/Controller/CommentController.php

line 128 ish.

and yes obviously one should use proper dependency injection but this should get you started ... also note you will test on the vbo result page not your custom form page.

Comment: This looks like a nice start, but I don't know where to put the `... return $response;` code as `$resultedTerms` is constructed inside `function executeMultiple` of `ActionBase`. I will add my code to be more clear

Comment: Maybe, my question is too easy... I understood the difficult part: how to send arguments to a route/form. But I don't know how to redirect to this form after the execution of the VBO Action. I feel this question is the easy part... this is why I don't have the answer. But maybe I am wrong.

Comment: then $url = "/path-to-form?terms=(implode('-',$resultedTerms)" return new RedirectResponse($url)
https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/vendor%21symfony%21http-foundation%21RedirectResponse.php/class/RedirectResponse/8.6.x